# Short Story-Experiment to hack metabolism via implant, patient escapes using keyboard to hack himself

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Not sure about more specifics, patient might have been voluntary or forced, but he hides a keyboard to connect into himself when alone and hacks himself to enable escape.  Implant control autonomous systems, and control metabolism, make himself stronger, etc.  Ends up escaping and never recovered by the facility later, using his implant for his own benefit.

The patient might have been overweight computer geek at the start, but the implant help him lose the fat and get into super physical shape.

Comment: When did you read this? Was it part of an anthology or in a magazine?

Answer (score 13):

I suspected the author was Cory Doctorow (just a feeling), so I started looking for the story. I'm pretty sure its "0wnzored", located [here.](http://www.salon.com/2002/08/28/0wnz0red/) The story involves a guy who learns to overclock his body and metabolism, giving him immunity to cancer and disease and all around physical perfection. He ends up escaping from the facility that was experimenting on him, which matches your memories.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you so much.

Comment: @user16539, Please accept the answer by ticking it, this will mark the question solved. For the details see: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)