# Story Identification: Short story about a man waking up and realizing he has an API to his body

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's a fairly fast read but I forgot the name.  Guy wakes up in a hospital/military facility by a computer.  Realizes he has an API into his own body.  Programs himself to get stronger which takes up energy so he gets hungry and eats a lot.  Then some stuff about memory/encrypting huge keys in his head.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: When did you read this story? Do you know if it was a fairly new story or an older one? Can you elaborate on what it meant to have an API? Was the story set in the present day or far future? Any details you can provide can be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good chance it's **Cory Doctorow**'s short story: *OwnzOred*. The main character; Murray Swain, is infected with a mutagen that allows him to interface with his body processes and reprogram them. His friend, Liam infected him with it. Liam was in the military hospital and was eating a lot of calories to allow to make the changes to his body.
The story is available here: [OwnzOred](https://www.salon.com/2002/08/28/0wnz0red)

Previously asked here: [Experiment to hack metabolism](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39155/short-story-experiment-to-hack-metabolism-via-implant-patient-escapes-using-key/39162#39162)